# Can't get information from git server using spring cloud config

Tags: linux, git, github, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Cloud Config project where I connect to my github account, my project works fine but here in my job my boss want to make a git server and use that instead of the github account, so after install git on my server (linux, I created a repository like this:

```
git init configuracionCarnet

cd configuracionCarnet

git pull <url from github>

git remote add origin user@ip:/home/desarrollo/configuracionCarnetDesarrollo.git
```

On my Spring cloud config project I change my application.yml like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: user@ip:/home/desarrollo/configuracionCarnet.git
          username: user
          password: password
server:
  port: 8001
```

I run the project and starts ok but when I execute the http://localhost:8001/health it throws that the project is down so I can't connect to the git server, what am I doing wrong?,

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) (and the following sections) for an introduction on setting up your own server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not create a server with `…remote add…`.

You also do not create a server with your Spring config by putting a non-existent URL into your config.

Possibilities:

1. Hide GitHub with Spring by putting your GitHub URL in your Spring config, as you did before.
2. Hide GitHub with a Gitblit mirror (you have to install Gitblit and google a bit)
3. Use Gitblit as a substitute for GitHub.